# LINEAR ALGEBRA how to find number of basic solutions

Tags: linear-programming

how can i find the total number of basic solutions to a linear programming problem
MAX Z= 2X-4Y Subject to
x+2y<3
3x+4y<5
x,y>0
How can we find total number of basic solutions.

Comment: Any basic solution has $m$ basic variables and $n-m$ non-basic variables where $n$ is the number of logical and structural variables and $m$ is the number of rows. The number of ways to pick $m$ out of $n$ is probably what you are looking for,

Answer (score 1):

There are as many basic solutions as intersections of your constraints.

Note: All basic solutions are not necessarily feasible.